# twitter-cassie : Error thrown on Cluster init

Tags: scala, playframework, cassandra, playframework-2.1

I am using playframework 2.1.0 and scala 2.10.
I have added cassie 0.20.0 from the twitter repo.

This line of code

```
val cluster = new Cluster("localhost", 9160)
```

Seems to provoke the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;
        at com.twitter.cassie.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.scala:50) ~[cassie-core-0.20.0.jar:na]
        at cassandra.Cassandra$.<init>(Cassandra.scala:13) ~[na:na]
        at cassandra.Cassandra$.<clinit>(Cassandra.scala) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$cassandraBloblAction$1.apply(Application.scala:41) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$cassandraBloblAction$1.apply(Application.scala:40) ~[na:na]
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Action.scala:254) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Using other constructors of Cluster leads to different exceptions of the same nature.

Comment: look like some dependency issue. Also make sure your compilation and runtime version are same

Comment: yeah it turned out to be that Cassie is scala 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of now :** Turns out twitter-cassie is only for scala 2.8.

This very succinct thread says it all :
 https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twitter-cassie/NS9f1NnyU6E

Twitter has not switched to scala 2.10 yet and nobody has put the work for it yet. I solved my problem by using Astyanax from cassandra.